# 403 Error if not logged in but my policy is set to return true

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

The policy is working if I am logged in but as soon as I am not logged in then the policy is not even being reached.

I do a `dd(__METHOD__);` withing the view() policy and when logged it it shows me the policy::view but when logged out it does not hit the policy

I have tried everything from changing roots, setting policy to true on everything.

I have tried different combinations on the parameters being given within the view()

For instance I have done things like this:

```
public function view(User $user): bool
    {
        dd(__METHOD__);
        return true;
    }
```

```
public function view(): bool
    {
        dd(__METHOD__);
        return true;
    }
```

```
public function view(User $user, Page $model): bool
    {
        dd(__METHOD__);
        return true;
    }
```

```
public function view(User $user, Page $model, String $name): bool
    {
        dd(__METHOD__);
        return true;
    }
```

Anyway here is my routes:

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\PageController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::controller(PageController::class)->group(function () {
        Route::get('/admin/pages', 'index')->name('admin.pages.index');

        Route::get('/admin/pages/create', 'create')->name('admin.pages.create');
        Route::post('/admin/pages/store', 'store')->name('admin.pages.store');

        Route::get('/admin/pages/{page}/edit', 'edit')->name('admin.pages.edit');
        Route::post('/admin/pages/{page}/update', 'update')->name('admin.pages.update');
        Route::delete('/admin/pages/{page}/delete', 'destroy')->name('admin.pages.delete');
    });
});

Route::get('/page/{page}/{name}', [PageController::class, 'show'])->name('page.show');
```

Here is my policy:

```
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\Models\Page;
use App\Models\User;

class PagePolicy
{
    /**
     * Determine whether the user can view any models.
     */
    public function viewAny(User $user): bool
    {
        return (bool)$user->is_admin;
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can view the model.
     */
    public function view(User $user, Page $model, String $name): bool
    {
        dd(__METHOD__);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can create models.
     */
    public function create(User $user): bool
    {
        return (bool)$user->is_admin;
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can update the model.
     */
    public function update(User $user, Page $model): bool
    {
        return (bool)$user->is_admin;
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can delete the model.
     */
    public function delete(User $user, Page $model): bool
    {
        return (bool)$user->is_admin;
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can restore the model.
     */
    public function restore(User $user, Page $model): bool
    {
        return (bool)$user->is_admin;
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can permanently delete the model.
     */
    public function forceDelete(User $user, Page $model): bool
    {
        return (bool)$user->is_admin;
    }
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Page;
use Inertia\Inertia;
use Inertia\Response;
use Intervention\Image\ImageManager;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;
use App\Http\Requests\StorePageRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use App\Http\Requests\UpdatePageRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Intervention\Image\Drivers\Gd\Driver;

class PageController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->authorizeResource(Page::class, 'page');
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     */
    public function index(): Response
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     */
    public function store(StorePageRequest $request): RedirectResponse
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     */
    public function show(Page $page, String $name)
    {
        return Inertia::render('Page/show', compact('page'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     */
    public function edit(Page $page)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     */
    public function update(UpdatePageRequest $request, Page $page)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     */
    public function destroy(Page $page): RedirectResponse
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Here is my AuthServiceProvider:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

// use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use App\Models\Page;
use App\Models\Setting;
use App\Policies\PagePolicy;
use App\Policies\SettingPolicy;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The model to policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array<class-string, class-string>
     */
    protected $policies = [
        Setting::class => SettingPolicy::class,
        Page::class => PagePolicy::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     */
    public function boot(): void
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();
    }
}
```

Comment: try making the `$user` optional in `view()` method in the PagePolicy: `public function view(?User $user, Page $page)`